# Keep getting ValueError when running while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code gives me the error "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" when running the infinite while loop with getting questions untill the user types no to break out of it. Any clue 1 more value is refering to ?

```
from random import shuffle
questions = [
("Which organization develops the 802 family of standards for wired and wireless LANs and     MANs?", "ieee"),
("What type of delivery uses data link layer addresses?", "local delivery"),
    ("What organization developed the OSI reference model that is used in networking?", "iso"),
    ("Which message delivery option is used when all devices need to receive the same message simultaneously?", "broadcast"),
    ("Which type of network design combines voice, video, and data on the same communication channel?", "converged"),
    ("During a routine inspection, a technician discovered that software that was installed on a computer was secretly collecting data about websites that were visited by users of the computer. Which type of threat is affecting this computer?", "spyware"),
    ("Which device acts as a gateway to allow hosts to send traffic to remote IP networks?", "local router"),
    ("What will a network administrator use to modify a configuration on a Cisco router?", "ios"),
    ("To save time, IOS commands may be partially entered and then completed by typing which key or key combination?", "tab"),
    ("An administrator measured the transfer of usable data across a 100 Mb/s physical channel over a given period of time and obtained 60 Mb/s. Which kind of measurement did the administrator obtain?", "goodput"),
]
shuffle (questions)
numRight = 0
numQuest = 0
wrong = []
print ("Welcome to my computer networking Quiz, based on Cisco material.")
while True:
    for questions, rightAnswer in questions:
        answer = input(questions + " ")
        if answer.lower() == rightAnswer:
            print("Congratulations, that is the right answer!")
            numRight += 1
            numQuest += 1        
            answer2 = input("Would you like to continue? Type yes or no: ")        
            if answer2.lower() == "no":
                break
        else:
            print("That is the wrong answer my friend!")
            numQuest += 1
            answer2 = input("Would you like to continue? Type yes or no: ")
            if answer2.lower() == "no":
                break
a = numRight
b = numQuest
def stats(a,b):
    return a/b*100
if stats(a,b) >= 60.0:
    print("You got", stats(a,b), "percent right. You pass!")
else:
    print("You got", stats(a,b), "percent right. You fail!")
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simple: the "break" call inside the loop is only "breaking" the loop over the for, but not over the while.
In order to solve it, you just need to keep a variable "break_while", initialized as false and use it as a condition for the while. When the user answers "no" then you set this variable to True and the while will stop:

```
 while (not break_while):

      ***

      if answer2.lower() == "no":
          break_while = True
          break
```

edit: taking a closer look at your code, you must be carefull with the usage of two different variables with the same name, namely "questions"

```
for questions, rightAnswer in questions:
    ***
```

You were getting this error because after the usage of break, the while was still active and the for sentence was being called again, but with the value of variable "questions" changed to a particular question, which is not a tuple and so the ValueError was being raised. 
Change the name of the first "questions" to "question" in order to avoid such a conflict.

Comment: I modified my while loop to what you suggested but I still keep getting the same error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/quiz.py", line 21, in <module>
    for questions, rightAnswer in questions:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @hogglas I tried the code myself and it is working fine ... did you change the variable "questions" in the first part of the for to "question" as well as in the "answer = input(question + " ")" call?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the question+questions variables. That solved my looping error and I now understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @hogglas please, mark my answer as the correct one if you consider that the answer is correct ;)